Format a SELECT query that avoids SQL injection taking multiple parameters
I'm using Python 3 and SQLAlchemy to create dynamically a query that selects all the products that fulfill the conditions and avoids SQL injection issues.
I get the following error: "List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries"
The code is something like this
data  =[{"deparment_id": "vegies", "country": "Mexico"},
        {"deparment_id": "vegies", "country": "Australia"},
        {"deparment_id": "beef", "country": "Australia"}]

sql= """SELECT *  FROM products WHERE (department_id = %s AND country = %s) OR (department_id = %s AND country = %s) 
OR (department_id = %s AND country = %s)"""

param = ['vegies', 'Mexico', 'vegies', 'Australia','beef', 'Australia']

res = session.execute(text(sql), param).fetchall()


I have not used sqlalchemy, but the error message suggests that the parameter field should be the data list.

This question is similar to: sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

sqlalchemy works better for injection protection when using its own mechanisms for query definition. Is there a good reason this query cannot be written in the form select(Product).where(Product.department_id == ...)? If you go straight to SQL strings, you've bypassed 90% of sqlalchemy's features, including all the automatic parameter sanitisation that occurs via .where().

You are already using SQLAlchemy, so let it build the query for you.
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///database.sqlite")

products = sa.Table("products", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

data = [{"department_id": "vegies", "country": "Mexico"},
        {"department_id": "vegies", "country": "Australia"},
        {"department_id": "beef", "country": "Australia"}]

where_cases = []
for case in data:
    criteria = [products.c[k] == v for k, v in case.items()]
    where_cases.append(sa.and_(*criteria))
where_clause = sa.or_(*where_cases)
qry = sa.select(products).where(where_clause)

engine.echo = True
with engine.begin() as conn:
    rows = conn.execute(qry).all()
    """
SELECT products.department_id, products.country 
FROM products 
WHERE products.department_id = ? AND products.country = ? OR products.department_id = ? AND products.country = ? OR products.department_id = ? AND products.country = ?
[generated in 0.00050s] ('vegies', 'Mexico', 'vegies', 'Australia', 'beef', 'Australia')
    """

